# Defining custom operators on polymorphic structure in C++ / RTTI usage relevance

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism, operator-overloading, rtti

Assume we have a class hierarchy in C++ as follows:

```
class A{
//...
};

class B : public A{
//...
};
```

`A` may represent an abstract base class and have a complicated structure of derived classes.
We define a `Sum` class which represents a sum of two `A` objects.
Hence we'd like to overload the `+` operator to take two `A` objects and return the corresponding `Sum` object:

```
Sum operator+(const &A a1, const &A a2){
//...
}
```

As `A` is an abstract class, we may want to implement `operator+()` differently for its subclasses.
For example, if `A` is `RealFunction` and `B` is `Polynomial`, we expect the result of addition of two polynomials to be a polynomial (the dynamic type) instead of the general `Sum` object (as we know how to add polynomials effectively).

What design is preferred in this situation? It seems that using RTTI to check the types would fit, but many people on stack said it should be avoided.

Comment: Well, your `operator+` sums two `A` objects and returns a `Sum`, that should be it's behaviour then. If you need a different behaviour, you can just implement `Polynomial operator+(RealFunction,Polynomial);`, I don't frankly see the issue.

Comment: The issue is that if I refer to two `Polynomial` objects with `RealFunction` references, I will still get the `Sum` object. I want the operator to behave as a virtual function which will do the right thing in runtime.

Comment: So write a virtual function that  `operator+` calls to do the work.